# How to install software in terminal in one line and one time?

Tags: command-line, apt

I want to create a code that I put my terminal to install few software at the same time.

For example, after a fresh install, I like to install this kind of software, but I have to line per line...

I want to do it in one time?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator

sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety
```

How I can put all this in the terminal in one shot?

How I can automatically set ENTER when I add the ppa and after set to Yes for the install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator  unity-tweak-tool variety
```

#### Purpose of &&:

let's say:

```
command one && command two
```

means execute the command two if and only if the  command one is successful. 
This prevent errors so if some command failed for some reason then the next commands will not run, but if you want to run commands even if there is an error then replace && with ; so that command become:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao ; sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator  unity-tweak-tool variety
```

Comment: Only problem I have with this: it becomes unreadable. I would prefer the method where commands are put inside a text file and that file is executed.

Comment: thanks for your answers, so it s working but how i can automatically set ENTER when i add the ppa and after set to Yes for the install? thanks

Comment: Yes thanks a lot Maythux. i will reedit the question and add this part. thanks again :-) that help me!

Comment: No reason to use yes | sudo apt-get for the install, simply use "sudo apt-get install -y PackagetoInstall"

Answer (score 4):

You can write a shell script `filename.sh`. Type:

`user@system:~$ gedit filename.sh`

Input the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao ; 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa ;
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator unity-tweak-tool variety
exit 0
```

Save the script. You can run the script by following command.

```
user@system:~$ /bin/bash filename.sh
```

After each fresh installation you can copy this script and run to install all packages in one go.

**OR**

If you want to run all commands in terminal as one line, you can try the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao ; sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa ; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator unity-tweak-tool variety
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answers, so it s working but how i can automatically set ENTER when i add the ppa and after set to Yes for the install? thanks

Comment: You can use `-y` to set ENTER : `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:atareao/atareao`